# How can i get list of custom model datas in formdata

Tags: angular, typescript, asp.net-core

I am unable to get the List of child details in the controller.
This is a model in asp.net

```
   public class TestFileModel
{
    //public TestFileModel()
    //{
    //    ChildrensDetails = new List<ChildrensDetailsDataModel1>();
    //}
    public IFormFile? Photo { get; set; }
    public List<ChildrensDetailsDataModel1> ChildrensDetails { get; set; }
    public List<string> Ids { get; set; }
}
public class ChildrensDetailsDataModel1
{
    public string ChildCountry { get; set; } = null!;
}
```

This is the controller

```
 [HttpPost]
    [Route("UpdateUser")]
    public async Task<JsonResult> UpdateUser([FromForm] TestFileModel userDetailModel)
    {
        var userslist = await _userBusiness.UpdateUser(userDetailModel);
        return new JsonResult(new { userslist });
    }
```

This is the Angular save method code and service file

```
if (this.profileForm.invalid)
  return;
let formData: FormData = new FormData();
formData.append('Photo', this.selectedFile);
for (let index = 0; index <  this.profileForm.value.childrensDetails.length; index++) {
  formData.append('ChildrensDetails', this.profileForm.value.childrensDetails[index])
}
for(let i = 0; i < this.chartDataSetValue.length; i++) {
  formData.append("Ids", this.chartDataSetValue[i].toString());
```

}

```
 updateUser(userDetailModel:any):Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post<any>(`${UserProfileURLConstants.USER_PROFILE}`,userDetailModel);
}
```

But I am able to get Ids value unable to get ChlidrensDetails value.
[Image for details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZTe5a.png)

Comment: Have you tried to put '[]' near your property name? formData.append('ChildrensDetails[]', this.profileForm.value.childrensDetails[index]) or try to use Json.Stringify on your array to convert it to string

Comment: @Serhii  I tried with both scenarios it's not worked

Comment: Check `Request.Form` property values inside the controller. Maybe you will find some discrepancy there

Answer (score 0):

Passing a set of objects via form-data is tricky that you can't straightly pass the object as:

```
ChildrensDetails[0]: { "ChildCountry": "Malaysia" }
ChildrensDetails[1]: { "ChildCountry": "Korea" }
```

Instead, you have to do as:

```
ChildrensDetails[0].ChildCountry: "Malaysia"
ChildrensDetails[1].ChildCountry: "Korea"
```

---

Assume `this.profileForm.value.childrensDetails[index]` returns value of:

```json
{ "childCountry": /* Country name */ }
```

Modify the `formData.append` part for `ChildrensDetails`.

```js
for (let index = 0; index < this.profileForm.value.childrensDetails.length; index++) {
  formData.append(`ChildrensDetails[${index}].ChildCountry`, 
    this.profileForm.value.childrensDetails[index].childCountry)
}
```

> Test Scenario & Output

[image]

[image]